# Why do I have absurd values with nympy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays

```
import numpy as np
a7=np.empty(100)
a7[0:14]=6 
a7[15:60]=4
a7[61:73]=5
a7[74:99]=6
print a7
```

Then

```
[  6.00000000e+000   6.00000000e+000   6.00000000e+000   6.00000000e+000
   6.00000000e+000   6.00000000e+000   6.00000000e+000   6.00000000e+000
   6.00000000e+000   6.00000000e+000   6.00000000e+000   6.00000000e+000
   6.00000000e+000   6.00000000e+000   6.95215775e-310   4.00000000e+000
   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000
   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000
   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000
   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000
   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000
   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000
   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000
   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000
   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000
   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000
   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000
   6.95215673e-310   5.00000000e+000   5.00000000e+000   5.00000000e+000
```

On every transition this abnormal value appears.Or may be I should fill up the array in a different manner?My idea was to create array with 100 elements and fill them in above shown manner.

Comment: What transition? Did you forget to tell us what you do with the array after you initialize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a7[0:14] = 6  #from 0 to 13, 14 excluded
a7[15:60] = 4 #from 15 to 60, 60 excluded etc.
```

When slicing, 2nd parameter is excluded so you are missing 14th-60th-73rd-99th elements of the array and python assigns them to something *really* close to zero since you created an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

First, you know, that the stop value of a slice is exclusive. So you do not initalize the elements 14, 60, 73 and 99.

Second, `np.empty` does not initialize the elements, so you want to use `np.zero` to set all elements to 0 initially.

Answer (score 0):

a[0:14] fills 14 values - 0...13. a[15:35] fills 15...35. So, in your code, a[14] is left unassigned, and whatever was in that memory address before remains there. That is the value you see.